# Unable to get Cobertura dependency in Jenkins: No plugin found for prefix 'cobertura' in the current project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

For some reason unknown to me, I am unable to get the cobertura plugin dependency via jenkins slave box. I had some proxy issues before but I thought they have been fixed.

This is the build error I get:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-04T11:54:21-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'cobertura' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/jenkins/mvnrepo), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

This is my settings.xml file:

```
<profile>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>local.central</id>
            <url>@localRepositoryUrl@</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>        

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>local.central</id>
            <url>@localRepositoryUrl@</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>         
    </pluginRepositories>

</profile>
```

Do I have these repositories correct? Any help or assistance would be much appreciated

Comment: what exactly is your plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was my proxy again. I had to add in my proxy settings under  in the default settings.xml file